# Extract pdf file on ftp server using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, itext, lucene.net

I am working on Document management project and I want to extract text from pdf. How can I achieve this. I am using Itextsharp to extract pdf on local system

This is a function I am using for this purpose. Path is a FTP Server Path

```
 public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
    {
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
            }

            return text.ToString();
        }
    }
```

It throws an exception

```
'ftp:\\###\index\500199.pdf not found as file or resource.'
```

[### is my ftp server]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem.

Comment: Want to extract text from pdf on ftp.. problem is when I write PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path) it thorows exception 'file not found as file or resource'

Comment: Put additional information in the question.

Comment: Okay. Edited @AmedeeVanGasse

Comment: Check that you can open the URL in a browser, or do `wget <URL>` at the console. Also, your slashes look backwards. Shouldn't ` \ ` be ` / `?

Comment: tried 'ftp://###/LuceneTest/PDFs/500199.pdf''.. but no luck.. this path work fine in browser @AmedeeVanGasse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PdfReader` has a bunch of constructor overloads but most of them rely on [`RandomAccessSourceFactory`](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/io/RandomAccessSourceFactory.cs) to convert whatever is passed in into a `Stream` format. When you pass a `string` in it is [checked](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/io/RandomAccessSourceFactory.cs#L147) if it is a file on disk and if not it is checked if it can be converted to a `Uri` as one of `file:/`, `http://` or `https://` link. This is your first point of failure because none of these checks handle the ftp protocol and you ultimately end up at a [local resource loader](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/io/StreamUtil.cs#L114) which doesn't work for you.

You *could* try converting your `string` to an explicit `Uri` but that actually won't work, either:

```
//This won't work
new PdfReader(new Uri(path))
```

The reason that this won't work is because [iText tells .Net to use `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/io/RandomAccessSourceFactory.cs#L114) when loading remote resources however that concept doesn't exist in the FTP world.

Long story short, when using FTP you'll want to download the files on your own. Depending on their size you'll want to either download them to disk or download them a byte array. Below is a sample of the latter:

```
Byte[] bytes;
if( path.StartsWith(@"ftp://")) {
    var wc = WebRequest.Create(path);
    using (var response = wc.GetResponse()) {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            bytes = iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.InputStreamToArray(responseStream);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then pass either the local file or the byte array to the `PdfReader` constructor.

Comment: thank you @chirs Hass .. Actual problem is : I Want to extract pdf from some other server.. I do not have any idea how to achieve this. Please advise me in this regard. Thank you

Comment: The code I posted above will allow you to download a file (PDF, whatever) from another server over FTP (HTTP(S) works, too). That's the first step and is totally unrelated to iText, its just straight .Net. The second step is to take the byte array from the first step and pass that to the `PdfReader` constructor instead of `path`.